# Install a second NuGet from the first

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I've created my own NuGet package, but I would also like the user to install another NuGet package alongside the one I install. Is there a way to automate this process in an install.ps1 script, or some way like that? For example, let's say when someone installs my nuget, I also want them to install "Newtonsoft.Json." Or is there a way to add another package as a dependency for the first one?

Comment: So I figured out how to add a dependency to the package I want to install from a .nuspec file, does anyone know how to do the same thing from a .csproj file? I found my answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#the-role-and-structure-of-the-nuspec-file), but I just need to figure out how to do it in a .csproj format now.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli#run-the-pack-command  any PackageReference in the project (that does not use PrivateAssets="all") becomes a package dependency